# Android Linear Layout with four Listview is not scrolling inside Scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I am using `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and inside that layout I am having four `ListView`. This layout I have placed inside `ScrollView`.

My problem is `ScrollView` is not scrolling. So I am not able to see my all list views.

What i am doing is:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="600dp"
android:fillViewport="true" >




             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/frag_capt2"
                 android:layout_width="800dp"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:orientation="vertical" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/linearlayoutteamtv1"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Medium Text"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                     android:textColor="#000000" />


                 <ListView
                     android:id="@+id/ListView01team"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:background="@drawable/pm_cool_listproject_background" >

                 </ListView>



                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/linearlayoutteamtv2"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:text="Medium Text"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                     android:textColor="#000000" />



                 <ListView
                     android:id="@+id/ListView02team"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:background="@drawable/pm_cool_listproject_background" >

                 </ListView>

                  <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/linearlayoutteamtv3"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:text="Medium Text"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                     android:textColor="#000000" />



                 <ListView
                     android:id="@+id/ListView03team"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:background="@drawable/pm_cool_listproject_background" >

                 </ListView>



                  <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/linearlayoutteamtv4"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:text="Medium Text"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                     android:textColor="#000000" />



                 <ListView
                     android:id="@+id/ListView04team"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:background="@drawable/pm_cool_listproject_background" >

                 </ListView>


             </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I do not understand what my code is missing.

Comment: Listview is not working inside scrollview

Comment: A ListView inside a ScrollView is a sign of bad design. I understand that you have a list of players, a header for each list of players and there's multiple list of players. A ListView can contain multiple "view types" (also google BaseAdapter). The contents of your ListView can then be <HEADER, PLAYER, PLAYER, PLAYER..., HEADER, PLAYER..., HEADER,...>

Answer (score 1):

A `listview` should **NOT** be inside any scrolling element or vice versa. please have a look at what google developers have to say about it.Please check this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Answer (score 1):

you can set all four listview height..like...

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lst_tree_hazard"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"       ///set the height based on your listview content
            android:scrollbars="none" >
 </ListView>
```

Comment: hey..mehul 1000 your code helped lot ...it solved my problem..thanks..i wanted to give you voteup..but my reputation is not equal to 15..sorry..

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have a `ScrollView` for a `ListView`. I think you can easily use `RelativeLayout` and specify the order of the `ListViews`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you cannot put scrollable things inside other scrollable things, where they scroll in the same direction, and have the results be reliable. Occasionally this works (e.g., `WebViews` in a `ViewPager`), but that is the exception, not the norm.

Either:

Move the `ListView` out of the `ScrollView`, or

Move all the rest of the contents of the ScrollView into the ListView, whether using things like `addHeaderView()` or my [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do that that way! However, there is solution to you problem, **multiple types of list items within single list**. Differences between single type list items:

- define list item types, ie. `(header, list1_type, list2_type,... main_header?, main_footer?)`, override [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount())
- override [`getItemViewType(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)),

  - `is index_of_header -> 0`
  - `is index_of_type1 -> 1`
  - `is index_of_type2 -> 2`
- more complex [`getView(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup))

  - get item view type, *hint: use already made function*
  - dispatch view creation based on type, don't forget, that `convertView` argument is view for current item type, you **should reuse it**, if not null!

You may create your own abstract class for merging adapter, as mentioned in another answer. It's just basically what I explained above. Sometimes you just can't use merge adapter, ie. recursive structures, but there is good idea to consider using [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).